# Is the topological space Hausdorff ($T_2$)?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, discrete-mathematics

Consider the prime numbers $\mathbb{P}$ and the topology
$$
T=\{\{\text{prime numbers not dividing }n\ \} | \text{ where } n\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\}
$$
My lecture notes state that this topological space is **not** Hausdorff, which, however, confuses me. The definition of Hausdorff:

> A topological space $(M,\mathscr{M})$ is Hausdorff if $\forall p,q\in M$ with $p\ne q$ there exist disjoint open subsets $O_1,O_2\in\mathscr{M}$ with $p\in O_1$ and $q\in O_2$.

Now, consider some subset of primes $P=\{p_1,p_2,...,p_k\}$ and the product $n=\prod_j n_j$ consisting of all $n_j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p_i\nmid n$ for all $i\in\{1,2,...,k\}$. Because the product $\prod_j n_j$ includes any prime number $\notin P$, we know that the only prime numbers that do not divide $n$ are those in the set $P$. Thus, any set of primes is in the topology $T$, which is therefore the discrete topology. All subsets of the discrete topology are both open and closed, so pick $O_1=\{p\}$ and $O_2=\{q\}$ with $p\ne q$. Then we have shown that the condition for a Hausdorff space is satisfied. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, what are the open sets in your topology? Open sets of the form $\{p:p\nmid n\}_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$?

Comment: @AlekosRobotis, see my edit. The topology consists of all sets of prime numbers that do not divide $n$ with $n$ being a positive integer.

Comment: @logi it looks to me that the topology should consist of sets $U_n$ where $U_n$ is the set of all primes not dividing $n.$ I.e. aren't you missing a pair of outer curly braces?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip, we should get a new set for each $n$ - you mean I should write $\{\text{prime numbers not dividing } n\}$?

Comment: @logi, no I think it you should have extra braces on the outside. I don't think that each prime not dividing $n$ is an open set, but that the collection of all primes not dividing $n$ is an open set.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip, the exact way the set was defined is $T=\{\mathbb{P}\setminus\{p\in \mathbb{P}|p\text{ divides }n\}|n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\}$

Comment: @logi which is what I was trying to tell you. If you define $U_n=\mathbb P\setminus\{p\in\mathbb P\,|\,p \text{ divides } n\}$, then $T=\{U_n\,|\, n\in \mathbb N\cup\{0\}\}$. There is one open set for each $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your product is infinite! For instance, if I set $P = \{ 2 \}$, then you have defined
$$
n = 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot \ldots
$$

This is clearly not a well-defined integer!

Stepping back a bit, you are attempting to find a number $n$ such that $p \mid n$ for all but a finite number of primes $p$. This is obviously impossible because there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: On that comment, how can I show that $\{2\}$ is closed? Does that follow directly from the fact that $T\setminus \{2\}$ is infinite, and therefore open (is any infinite set open)?

Comment: The set $\{ p : p \nmid 2 \}$ is one of the open sets according to your topology. It is exactly the set of primes not equal to $2$. Therefore its complement, $\{ 2 \}$, is closed.